# Edit otherwise valid answer to remove "Also, look at that long list of maybe solutions"?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, websites

I often see this:

```
Q: Chat server with feature X?                             <- valid question

A: I like MyChatX3, a chat server with feature X           <- valid answer
   Also, look at http://random/list-of-chat-apps           <- worthless?
```

The first part of the answer is OK, but I feel that the last sentence is useless.
Linking to a web page listing tools that *might* be on-topic sounds counter-productive:

- Newcomers are lead to believe that posting a link is a valid answer.
- It reduces the meaningfulness of the votes on this post: Did people upvote MyChatX3, or one of the tools in the list?

What to do (or not) in such cases?

Answer (score 4):

Good observation, Nicolas.

When I see that type of answer, I often wonder "What is wrong with the answer that they decided to also include a link to a list of apps?".

I then reread the answer at least one more time.

I've found that sometimes the answer is somehow lacking (does not really address all the feature requirements).  In that case, I add a comment asking for more details.

Other times, I've found that the answer is great, but they are providing an *additional resource* in case the OP wants to see other options.

I get tempted to remove the link to the list of apps, but honestly, I sometimes find those links very useful, so I generally don't touch them.  The big downside is that the links can become invalid, so the answer must always standalone as a valid answer without the link.

Regarding the meaningfulness of the votes, I understand your concern, and at the same time I personally don't find that to be an issue.  I think most of the time people are voting for the software recommended, and not for the link to the list.  I hope that if someone finds an equal or better solution from the linked list that they will post it as a separate answer, thereby helping our entire community.

Answer (score 2):

I find RockPaperLizard's paragraph about "*lacking answers*" very true. Answers that have such links are often lacking something else. Often the answer would otherwise be a one-line answer (which usually attracts downvotes), and the author added the link as if thinking "*I must write a bit more to make it (look like?) a valid answer*".

I would go further than RockPaperLizard and **allow** people to **remove such links** if they are familiar with the topic and feel that the web page linked to does not add much value.

Example: For a question "Linux raster image editor", a webpage that talks about GIMP and Inkscape is not very useful, as half of the results do not fit.

I would encourage people who remove a link to open the webpage once, and add as answers the valid tools that they use and like.